# Generating a regex from a function in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need a function that could generate a regex.  For example if I write

```
$pat = "My {$var} is {$var2}"
```

to generate a regex that when I use

```
preg_match($pat,"My name is Kevin",$matches);
```

to return

```
$matches[1] = 'name';
$matches[2] = 'Kevin';
```

and the the string could be : "My $nameword is $name and i'm $age years old"

And the problem is:

```
FIG1
<?php
function gen_pattern($string)
{
<--- add code for generating pattern --->
}
?>

FIG2
$pat = gen_pattern('my name is {$X}');
ereg($pat,'my name is moo',$regs);
//$regs[1] == "moo„
([^\s]*)

$pat = gen_pattern('my {$YZ} is {$IJK}');
ereg($pat,'my name is moo',$regs);
//$regs[1] == "name", $regs[2] == "moo"
```

My homework's description is as follows:

> Figure 1 shows a function which can generate a regular expression, usable for the ereg function.
>
> Figure 2 shows how the pattern should work. In the given string, each item {$ABC} represents a placeholder, i.e. {$X} is the single place holder in "my name is {$X}", and there are two place holders in "my {$YZ} is {$IJK}". A place holder can be of any length above zero.
>
> In the resulting pattern, each place holder represents one single word of the text, which has to be added to the result list. I.e. {$X} represents the next word after "my name is". As a result, $regs[1] becomes "moo" if the pattern is used on text "my name is moo". Assume that we have only texts of form [a-z ]* (note the white space).

My Task:

> Fill in the green spot in Figure 1. Dont bother with error handling or checking the correct syntax of given string (i.e. "my name is {{}" or similar invalid input will not occur).

And I don't know where to begin.

Comment: the `ereg*` family of functions is deprecated. You should not use them anymore. use the `preg_*` family of functions instead.

Comment: This homework is deprecated too ;)

Comment: Nice question, much better than usual homework Qs here. Correctly tagged as homework and well formatted, +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may work:

```
function gen_pattern($str){
    $str = preg_replace('/(\{[\$a-zA-Z]+\})/', '(\w+)', $str);
    return '/'.$str.'/';
}
$p = gen_pattern('my {$xx} is {$X}');

preg_match($p, 'my name is moo', $m);
```

`$m` will be:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(14) "my name is moo"
  [1] =>
  string(4) "name"
  [2] =>
  string(3) "moo"
}
```

Comment: wow man, this is insane, you answered so fast ... it works, but i don't understand for the love of god that regex, it seems that is replace something ... i don't know, do you have a tutorial or link for this? thank you

Comment: @RowMinds tutorial... try to look [here](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php)

Comment: and what does it means '(\w+)' , is like "retrive the matched pattern" ?

Comment: `\w` = "word", means `[a-zA-Z]` and some other chars which i don't remember. `+` means one or more, `()` means "save it" so it can be accessed by `$m` in `preg_match`

Comment: When building a regex dynamically, always make use of [preg_quote](http://www.php.net/preg_quote)(). Otherwise you face the possibility that the regex breaks, or works unintended, or in the worst case... calls eval and executes arbitrary code (the e flag, although your code isnt vulnerable here ... its getting close).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will help you..:

```
function gen_pattern($string)
{
    return "@".preg_replace("@(\{\$(.*?)\})@msi", "(?P<$2>.*?)", $string)."@";
}
```

so you will get a result with your variables as keys.

Comment: hey, please try it now :) if it will not work too, change $2 to $1 in my code. sorry, i didnt tested it, but if it will work, it will give you results with keys as your variable names..